# Coefficient standard error for "GLM" not in exponential family

Tags: generalized-linear-model, standard-error, fisher-information, hessian

For GLMs in the exponential family, we can obtain the standard errors for the regression coefficients as a function of the diagonal of the fisher information matrix. Does this still hold if the regression distribution is not in the exponential family (this is of course technically not a GLM but I'm not sure if there is a technical name for this kind of model)? For example, beta-binomial or dirchlet-multinomial? In this case, does it instead become necessary to use the diagonal of the Hessian?